# Script not working inside foreach, how to run it via ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have been trying to make a script work after clicking a table. Pretty much, when you visit your favorite email provider, you click on a new email and it opens up, that is what I am aiming for. I haven't been able to run ckeditor after the click.

### retrieve data and post to table

```
$getInfo = $articleClass->get_all_article_info();

foreach($getInfo as $data)
{
    $article_title = $data['article_title'];
    $article_content = substr(htmlentities($data['article_content']),0,50).'...';
    $article_content_full = $data['article_content'];

    echo '
        <tr id="tr_id">
            <td class="marker">
                <i class="fa fa-align-left"></i>
            </td>

            <td class="title">
                '.$article_title.'
            </td>

            <td class="content">
                '.$article_content.'
            </td>
        </tr>

        <section id="post_info_id" style="display:none;">

            <textarea id="editor1" name="editor1"></textarea>

            <script>
                CKEDITOR.replace( "editor1",
                {
                    toolbar: "Basic",
                });

                CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData( "'.$article_content_full.'", function()
                {
                    this.checkDirty();
                });
            </script>

        </section>
    ';
}
```

### clicking action on table

```
$(document).ready(
function()
{
    $("#tr_id").click(function()
    {
        $("#post_info_id").css("display", "block");
        $("#table_id").hide();
    });
});
```

### Issue

When I click on a row, it just opens the editor1 textarea, but not the script I am wanting to load. If I remove the first script I posted above that is inside the echo and put it on the footer of the .php file, the script loads just fine but I need it inside the foreach otherwise it will not work, how do I make it run on ajax? I have absolutely no experience with ajax, but willing to learn.

### EDIT:

I cannot figure out how to make this piece of code inside ajax.

```
CKEDITOR.replace( "editor1",
{
    toolbar: "Basic",
});

CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData( "'.$article_content_full.'", function()
{
    this.checkDirty();
});
```

Comment: From where the Ajax comes in picture??

Comment: I included an edit in my question.

Comment: I have two solution for you.. one without ajax and one with ajax. tell me your choice.

Comment: @RiteshChandora, the one that causes you less trouble. :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.
this code will create one Ck-editor instance.
Your article_content_full detail will be added in hidden div. and on row click it will be fetched and displayed with ck-editor.

```
  $getInfo = $articleClass->get_all_article_info();    
  foreach($getInfo as $data) {
    $article_title = $data['article_title'];
    $article_content = substr(htmlentities($data['article_content']),0,50).'...';
    $article_content_full = $data['article_content'];

    echo '<tr id="tr_id">
            <td class="marker">
                <i class="fa fa-align-left"></i>
            </td>

            <td class="title">
                '.$article_title.'
            </td>

            <td class="content">
                '.$article_content.'<div id="article_content_full" style="display:none;">'.$article_content_full.'</div>
            </td>
        </tr>        
    '; }
      echo '<section id="post_info_id" style="display:none;">
            <textarea id="editor1" name="editor1"></textarea>
        </section>';



   $(document).ready(
    $("#tr_id").click(function() {
        $("#post_info_id").css("display", "block");
        $("#table_id").hide();
        var config = {};
        var html = $(this).find('#article_content_full').html()
        editor = CKEDITOR.appendTo( 'editor1', config, html );      
    }); 
  });
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a little bit confused. If the article_content_full is inside the tr_id, won't it be hidden as well when the button is clicked?

Comment: try to run it and tell me the output.

Comment: When I click a row, nothing changes at all. PS: your curly bracket is out of place.

Comment: I was able to accomplish by simply using window.onload for the ckeditor replace.